# OpenCart boxed products

Tags: php, opencart, subscription

I am trying to implement a concept in which the user can choose among a selection of products, and create a boxed compilation of products. The products to be included in the box won't have any price, the box will have a price (fixed one, regardless of the selected products), and to be more precise, the user will pay for the box via a subscription. So the user will pay for a 3/6/12 months subscription and will be able to create 3/6/12 compilations of products, one for each month.

Can this be implemented only via configuration? Can I create a product, with a fixed price, and set some items, as the options for this product? So, in this case, the box will be the product, its price will be fixed, actually it has no price, the user must have paid his subscription, and the options are which items the user can include in the box.

On checkout, I need to add a check if the user has paid for his subscription and some other checks, found in this post: [OpenCart subscription model (x months)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244247/opencart-subscription-model-x-months)

Any ideas? Is this feasible, and if so, how from a really high, architectural, point of view?

Cheers,
Iraklis

Answer (score 0):

If you create a single product for the box, then create options for the products you are offering for selection then yes this can be done using opencart. I would recommend you use check boxes for the options, though if you want to limit the number selected, that may require further tweaking.

As for the subscription model, sure in theory that can be added and is something I've done for a couple of clients in the past. I think there are extensions already made that do it too in the extension store

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for you reply, can you please add some links for subscription extensions, or just write down, from a really high level point of view, how you achieved this functionality?

Comment: As for the products selection, I would like to have exactly this functionality, http://beautyfix.com/products_selection.php, could that be implemented with product options? How can I add the content (image and description) for each option/item?

Comment: For the subscription extensions, you can search the extension directory for them. I've never used one from there but sure they exist. For how its done, it depends how you want it to function but essentially you set either vouchers or products up with an additional parameter which can be read during the checkout to then hook into and set up the customer accordingly