# Automatic link in admin menu

Tags: admin, opencart

I've followed this small tutorial, and made what i needed:
[Stackoverflow - Custom admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700761/how-to-create-a-custom-admin-page-in-opencart)

But now i needed to put a link to it in the admin menu, automaticly when I upload my files to the server...

How can I do it? :s googled for it, but I think I couldn't find the answer :s

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done automatically when you upload the files to the server. You will need to create a vQmod to edit the admin header files to insert it

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us what version of opencart you are using, do you have vqmod (do you intend to use it at all), and where would you like that page link to show up in admin panel.

You need to install [vqmod](http://code.google.com/p/vqmod/) (follow instructions)

create .xml file, save it to vqmod XML folder and put this in it

```
<modification>
    <id>Add a link</id>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
    <vqmver>0.1</vqmver>
    <author>Jeffrey Murdock</author>

    <!-- edit header controller -->
    <file name="admin/controller/common/header.php">
    <!-- create link to your page -->   
        <operation error="log">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[$this->data['setting'] = $this->url->link('setting/store', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            $this->data['hello_world'] = $this->url->link('custom/helloworld', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    <!-- / -->
    </file>

    <!-- edit header template -->
    <file name="admin/view/template/common/header.tpl">
    <!-- add link to your page -->  
        <operation error="log">
            <search position="before" offset="1"><![CDATA[<ul class="right">]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <li><a class="top">Your link</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?=$hello_world;?>">Hello World</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    <!-- / -->
    </file> 

</modification>
```

If you installed vqmod properly, and have opencart 1.5.4 version, this should display link in your administrator top menu.