# OpenCart problems adding new admin pages

Tags: php, opencart

So, I followed:

[How to create a custom admin page in opencart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700761/how-to-create-a-custom-admin-page-in-opencart)

This tut to try and add a page to my OpenCart v1.5.6 shop.

```
<?
class ControllerCommonHelloworld extends Controller { 
public function index(){
            // VARS
            $template="common/hello.tpl"; // .tpl location and file
    $this->load->model('common/hello');
    $this->template = ''.$template.'';
    $this->children = array(
        'common/header',
        'common/footer'
    );      
    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    }
}
?>
```

but upon opening the new page am fed with this:

```
load->model('common/hello'); $this->template = ''.$template.''; $this->children = array('common/header', 'common/footer' ); $this->response->setOutput($this->render()); } }?>
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Controllercommonhelloworld' not found in ------\store\system\engine\front.php on line 39
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0015  303736  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0634  2285056 Front->dispatch( )  ..\index.php:166
3   0.0663  2439760 Front->execute( )   ..\front.php:29`
```

now as far as I am aware this error is telling me I have no Class named "ControllerCommonHelloworld" even though I have a file called helloworld.php

I have both of these things, and have tried all types of case combinations, and moving the files around...

does anyone know of any other reason this error might be appearing? or can see anything else I might have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server doesn't seem to be able to use php short tags. Change `<?` to `<?php` - Since PHP doesn't load that file as a PHP file, the class doesn't exist. Changing it to `<?php` will get it working

Comment: Really wish I had seen that. slap head situation. Thanks

Comment: You should also change this: `$this->template = ''.$template.'';` to: `$this->template = 'common/hello.tpl';` there's no need to redeclare this.